# Json check key-value pair exist dynamically

Tags: jquery, json

I have this data

```
 "Vitals":[
     {
     "Bp Systolic":"",
     "Bp Diastolic":"",
     "Weight":"",
     "Height":"",
     "BMI":""
     } 
   ],
   "Lab":[
    {
    "Lipid_profile":[{
      "Total Cholestrol":"",
      "TRIGLYCERIDES":""
      }],
    "blood":[{
      "A1C":[{"asd":""}],
      "ALBUMIN":"",
      "CALCIUM":"",
      "Glucose":"",
      "POTTASIUM":""
    }]
    }]
   };
```

Now for example when i click a button call blood. It should get the all values inside the blood. I have did that. But I have the first value as an another array. I want to check dynamically till all become empty key value pair. How can i find arrays and iterate through it dynamically till no array key value pair exist. I have done the sample program to make things clear.

[Check this out](http://jsfiddle.net/1f0wwrst/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My idea is to find all parents of clicked `li` using `data-parent`, then to use this chain of parents to find selected (clicked) `li` entry in `data` and, finally, to add found entry info as `li` sub-menu.

Also I added closing (actually, removing) sub-menu on second `li` click.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1f0wwrst/5/).

```
var data =
{
    ...
};

var html = "";
$.each(data, function(key, value)
{
    html += '<li id="' + key + '">' + key + '</li>';
});
$('#list').append(html);

$("#list").on('click', 'li', function()
{
    var jThis = $(this);
    if (jThis.hasClass("selected")) //close sub-menu on second click
    {
        jThis.find('ul').remove();
        jThis.removeClass('selected');
        return false;
    }
    var section = this.id;
    var parent = jThis.data('parent');
    var chain = [section];
    while (parent) //searching full chain of parents up to data
    {
        chain.push(parent);
        parent = $('#' + parent).data('parent');
    }
    var selectedValue = [data];
    for (var i = chain.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) //searching selected(clicked) element in data
    {
        var found = false;
        $.each(selectedValue, function(o_key, o_val)
        {
            $.each(o_val, function(i_key, i_val)
            {
                if (i_key == chain[i])
                {
                    selectedValue = i_val;
                    found = true;
                    return false;
                }
            });
            if (found)
            {
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
    var html = "<ul>"; // adding sub-menu
    $.each(selectedValue, function(o_key, o_val)
    {
        $.each(o_val, function (i_key, i_val)
        {
            html += '<li id="' + i_key + '" data-parent="' + section + '">' + i_key + '</li>';
        });
    });
    html += "</ul>";
    jThis.append(html);
    jThis.addClass('selected'); // registering first click
    return false;
});
```

**Update**. Full explanation:

- Adding first-level `li` to `#list` is clear enough - I just modified it a little bit for better perfomance.
- `$("#list").on('click', 'li'` is more appropriate way to add event handler (to static element `#list` instead of `document`).
- `if (jThis.hasClass("selected")) { ... }` block is used to check if this element was already clicked. If was clicked - then remove its sub-menu and the fact (the class) that it was already clicked.
- `var chain = [section];` and `while (parent) { ... }` are used to form list of all clicked element parents. By parents I mean elements (from top menu level), in which sub-menus clicked element is presented.
- Using these parents in `chain` list we can find clicked element inside `data` (by starting from `data`, searching for `parent1` in it, then searching for `parent2` in `data[xx][parent1]` and so on until clicked element info is found (by comparing clicked element ID with info key).
- When clicked element info is found in `data`, it is added as element sub-menu. Adding works as in original code, there is only small modifying to only one `.append()` once more for better perfomance.
- Finally class `selected` is added to clicked element to register the fact that element is already clicked (and its sub-menu is opened).

Comment: @divakar well, I added more explanations in **Update**.

Comment: can you help me in detection element who is not having child? for example Bp_systolic ???